# Controller action not being found when passing an options hash for specific controller and action in a form_for block

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, form-for

I'm trying to create a form in rails 4 using form_for based on an object representing a training course. Before loading the page, the app checks whether the current user has already signed up for the course. If not, then the submit button on the form creates a new 'signup' marking the course id and the user id in the signups table. This works correctly.

If the user is already signed up then I'd like the submit button to have  a different function - to make a get request for the particular signup record and show the details of it on the screen. Essentially like a re-direct to 'signups/id'. This is not working however.

This is the form displayed if the user is not signed up. It triggers a post request to the create action in the signups controller (and it works):

```
 <%= form_for course, :url => {:controller => "signups", :action => "create"}, :method => "post" do |f| %> 

    <%= hidden_field_tag :course_id, course.id %>

    <%= f.label :"Course Title" %>
    <%= f.text_field :courseTitle, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :"Course Title" %>
    <%= f.text_field :courseTitle, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :"Detailed Description Of Course Dates & Times" %>
    <%= f.text_area :courseDatesAndTimes, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :"General Course Location eg 'Malaga'" %>
    <%= f.text_field :courseGeneralLocation, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :"Exact Course Address including Postal Code" %>
    <%= f.text_field :courseExactAddress, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :"Course Description" %>
    <%= f.text_area :courseDescription, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :"Maximum Number of Students" %>
    <%= f.text_field :courseMaximumNumberStudents, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :"Normal Course Price" %>
    <%= f.text_field :courseNormalPrice, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :"'Listener' Course Price" %>
    <%= f.text_field :courseListenerPrice, class: 'form-control' %>          

    <%= f.submit "Sign Up!", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

  <% end %>
```

This is the form displayed if the user is already signed up to the course:

```
  <%= form_for course, :url => {:controller => "signups", :action => "show", params: {id: course.id}}, :method => "get" do |f| %> 

    <%= hidden_field_tag :course_id, course.id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id %>

    <%= f.label :"Course Title" %>
    <%= f.text_field :courseTitle, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :"Course Title" %>
    <%= f.text_field :courseTitle, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :"Detailed Description Of Course Dates & Times" %>
    <%= f.text_area :courseDatesAndTimes, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :"General Course Location eg 'Malaga'" %>
    <%= f.text_field :courseGeneralLocation, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :"Exact Course Address including Postal Code" %>
    <%= f.text_field :courseExactAddress, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :"Course Description" %>
    <%= f.text_area :courseDescription, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :"Maximum Number of Students" %>
    <%= f.text_field :courseMaximumNumberStudents, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :"Normal Course Price" %>
    <%= f.text_field :courseNormalPrice, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :"'Listener' Course Price" %>
    <%= f.text_field :courseListenerPrice, class: 'form-control' %>


    <%= f.submit "You're Signed Up! View Details", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

  <% end %>
```

This does not work - I get the error:

ActionController::UrlGenerationError in CoursesController#index
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"signups"}

The show action is in the signups_controller (right below the functioning 'Create' action) like so:

```
def show
  @courseID = params[:course_id]
  @userID = current_user.id
  @signup = getSignup(@courseID,@userID)
  redirect_to signups(@signup)
end
```

...and in the routes.rb file I simply have the following line:

```
resources :signups
```

I've tried to read the rails guides on routing, and the form_for guides on how the options should be tailored to correctly call a different action in a different controller but I think I'm missing some basic knowledge here as I can't get it to call the show action in the signups controller, seemingly because of a routes.rb problem.

Can anybody tell me whats wrong?

Thank-you!

Comment: `params: {id: course.id}}` is unnecessary just use `id: course.id`

Comment: also - if they are already signed up, why display the form at all... why not just redirect them to the course straight away?

Comment: Thanks for the input! The user has to do certain preparation tasks before the course starts so its important that they can see from the courses list which ones they are signed up to and be able to enter snd perform the pre-course tasks they are already signed up for.

Comment: Yes, but for that, they just need the course show page... they don't need to see the "sign up for the course" form. They never need to see this form at all, but instead, the "new" action should redirect them directly to the show page

Comment: The user needs to be able to go to The signup page to view and edit The signup details not only when they first sign up but later when they have already signed up. They need a link or button of some kind as the web app won't decide for the user when they have to complete the tasks, the user decides.

Comment: Ok, there's al kinds of assumed knowledge that you aren't including here.
Standard RESTful rails has these action as: :new :crate :edit :update - :show - they each do different things. The way it normally works is: :new and :edit display the form_for... and rails is smart enough to accept either an existing resource (`course` in this instance) in the form_for and itis smart enough to determine that a form_for a *new* course will POST to :create, but a form_for an *existing* course will PATCH to :update instead. That's how it works all by itself without you needing to put the url in the form.

Comment: By default, a standard generated RESTful rails controller will automatically redirect to the :show page of a course after you create or update it... you don't need to do that yourself - and certainly not in the form. You most definitey don't need to put that in a url-block in the form - because you really can't post a form to a get - that's not how it works (and it's dangerous to boot).

Comment: If you want specific, non RESTful behaviour - rather than exploining it in tiny pieces here in the comments - please update your question and give a full run-down of how your app departs from standard RESTful practice and WHY and what you expect to happen instead - under which circumstance - because otherwise it'll be impossible for us to hep you debug it.

Comment: You also need to explain what a "signup" is - because you are using the word "signup' but you have described code for a "course" - how do these two different things interact? If they are not different things, then please go through your question and remove the word "signup" and instead refer to things as "creating a course" because it's really confusing when you use different words for the same thing (you can display whatever you like to the users, but we are looking at the code here).

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
<%= form_for course, :url => {:controller => "signups", :action => "show", params: {id: course.id}}, :method => "get" do |f| %>
```

with

```
<%= form_for course, url: signup_path(course) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks! I switched out as you suggested and got the error message:  'param is missing or the value is empty: signup'. Howeve the error suggested that a patch request was being sent rather than a get request as I wanted, so I added the action as follows: '<%= form_for course, url: signup_path(course), :method => 'get' do |f| %>' and it does indeed call the show action in the signups controller. I really appreciate the suggestion but would you be able to explain why this works where the original form_for options hash did not?